# Angular 5 Detecting scroll events in mat-sidenav-container

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material2, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 with Material 2 and i'm trying to get a scrollevent to fire inside a component that is being wrapped by a `mat-sidenav-container` but it is not being run.

navbar.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" fullscreen>
            <mat-toolbar color="primary">
                    <button mat-button [routerLink] ="['']"><span>Home</span></button>
            </mat-toolbar>

            <div id="mainscroll">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
            </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            alert("Test");
        });
        $(window).ready(function() {
            $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
                alert("Test");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If I move the div along with the router outlet to be outside the `mat-sidenav-container`, the event are able to fire, but once I move them inside, the events do not fire, this is probably happening because the window itself is not being scrolled but rather the content.

I tried to use `$(mainscroll).scroll(function(){` but that is also not being detected, I could put a `(scroll)="myMethod()"` inside the navbar component but I need the scroll event to fire only for the home component and not other components.

If I put a console.log or alert inside `$(window).ready` it runs fine, so I know there is no issue with the JQuery not being run.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Scrolling package of the CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)? It's also unusual/discouraged to be using jQuery alongside Angular, as jQuery performs DOM manipulations and changes that Angular wouldn't 'know' about.

Comment: I haven't looked into the scrolling package, I looked around at that page you linked, but i'm not sure how to implement that. Regarding the JQuery, I was trying to use a host listener before, '@HostListener("window:scroll", [])' but had no luck with that either, so I was giving JQuery a try